# Can't start Tomcat in Eclipse (Mac OS X) - java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat

I have problem using Tomcat v.7.0 on Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.8.2.
I assume the problem is that I have another older version of Tomcat running on the same notebook. But I'm unable to find it and close it / kill it.

When I try to start Tomcat on Eclipse then I get following error:

```
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
```

Full log is below.

I tried with spotlight and with program Find Any File (http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php) to find where my Tomcat installations are. I looked for keyword 'catalina.sh' and I deleted all the parent folders for these findings.
I also deleted my eclipse workspace and reinstalled eclipse. Booted my notebook. Didn't help.

When I did a port scan then it didn't reveal anything. See screenshot:

[image]

Please advise how should I find out what's bugging Tomcat and how should I remove it.

(I'm new to Java EE and Mac OSX)

```
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1553 ms
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 719 ms
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
    java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 10, 2012 2:45:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something already running on the same port you are trying to start Tomcat on.

```
 sudo lsof -i :8080 # checks port 80
```

The default is 8080, it's set in server.xml in the Tomcat conf directory.

Comment: Thanks NimChimpsky. Don't know if it was this sudo lsof or it was something else I did. But now I got it Tomcat running and HelloWorld working.

Comment: after that kill the process with the given PID: kill PID

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by specifying

`<Server address="0.0.0.0" port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">`

at conf/server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

to my `CATALINA_OPTS` fixed this for me. Apparently localhost wasn't setup on IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Author of FAF here :)

I am no Tomcat expert but I suggest you subscribe to the "Macos-x-server" list at lists.apple.com and ask for help there.

Also, did Tomcat ever run on that system? If not, maybe you configured an illegal port. Try changing the port number to one above 1024 and see if that helps.

Lastly, I think you're asking on the wrong site. This is for programming questions. There are other OSX/Server specific sites next to SO that might be the better one to ask this.

Comment: Yes Tomcat run year ago on that system. But I forgot it and configured eclipse to run w. newer version - without removing old version. Will ask similar questions on OSX specific site in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have only one network device going. My problem was resolved as soon as I switched of my WiFi connection to only use my ethernet connection at work. At home the WiFi works fine as that is the only connection I have there.

Do not know why this is happening, I would guess is that Tomcat is getting confused with devices and assigning ports incorrectly.